# Addition of NaCl to the Anode Side of a Zinc-Copper Votaic Cell

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

I used a NaCl solution with a Zinc electrode in an otherwise standard voltaic cell with a Potassium Nitrate Salt Bridge and Copper Sulfate solution in the Cathode side. All the solutions were 1M.

I had assumed nothing wouldve happened but I got a result of 4mV. I used two different multimeters both with a uncertainty of 0.1mV so I am pretty sure that this was an actual voltage and this experiment did not work with water when I tried so I think that the NaCl solution is doing something. But I have no idea how it may have changed the half reactions.

I have read a similar post which talked about the creation of tetrachlorozincate but I am not sure if that is what is happening here so I am asking for some insight.

Comment: What was the dimension and the nature of the bridge between the two compartments ? Was it an agar gel ? Was it a blotting paper ? How long ? How thick ?  If the bridge had a strong internal resistance, you may have gotten only $4$ mV between the two electrodes.

Comment: The salt bridge was a U-Tube filled with a Potassium Nitrate solution with cotton balls at the end. To clarify, a wire was used to connect the electrodes and multimeter was connected to this wire. Would the internal resistance of the salt bridge affect the overall resistance?